# How to prevent statements from being reordered by the JVM

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm

is there way to ensure that doA is executed before doB?  One thing I thought of was wrapping each statement in a synchronized block.

```
object1.doA();
object2.doB();
```

Do method calls on a volatile variable act as volatile writes?

Edit - what I actually need is for other threads to see the effects of doA before those of doB.

Comment: In the same thread or in different threads?

Comment: No; those are regular reads.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I need other threads to see the effects of doA before those of doB

Comment: JVM *must* execute doA before doB. If you have an issue it's due to something else.

Comment: @alex that's a different thing and irrelevant of execution order. Add that to your question.

Comment: @eis Not necessarily, if the outcome of `doA` does not effect `doB` the JVM has every right to order `doB` ahead of `doA`

Comment: @eis technically, the JVM may execute doB before doA as long as it makes no difference. For example if you have `void doA() { a++; }` and `void doB() { b++; }` the two methods may be reordered because it does not change your program. However it may make a difference if another thread observes the data between the two methods.

Answer (score 2):

These statements won't be reordered from the perspective of the thread that executes that piece of code (they may be reordered in practice, but only if the reordering has no effect from the perspective of that thread).

However another thread may see the results of `doB` before seeing the results of `doA`. If that is an issue, you should lock around the code to make it atomic, for example by using a `synchronized` block.

Note that using two `synchronized` blocks does not achieve much - in particular it is very likely that the JVM will merge them into one anyway (assuming they use the same monitor, but if they don't then you won't necessarily achieve atomicity).

Comment: Well, I don't need atomicity - so the best way is to sync on Object1, doA(), (exit sync), sync on Object2, doB() ?  I was hoping there was a more succinct alternative.

Comment: @alex That is (probably) not enough - if you use two monitors you don't introduce any happens-before relationship between the two methods.

Comment: @alex assylias is 100% correct.  You should read more into how to maintain happens-before ordering.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on where you observe the effects of the calls to `doA()` and `doB()` from.

- If you observe the effects from the same thread as is executing the calls, then you are guaranteed to see them as is there had been no reordering.  Reordering is not allowed to change the single-threaded behaviour.  If the code as written says that `doA()` is called before `doB()`, then that is what the thread will observe ... if it is looking.  In short, no surprises.
- If you observe the effects from a different thread, then that thread is guaranteed to be able to observe a state consistent with the single-threaded case *at synchronization points*.  However if one thread attempts to observe the actions of another thread *without* proper synchronization, then it *may* observe the effects of reordering.

So ...

> How to prevent statements from being reordered by the JVM

Actually, I don't think that you can.  But if you code your (multi-threaded) application correctly, it won't be able to *observe* the effects of reordering.  And if it can't observe the effects, it doesn't make any difference to the behaviour if there is or isn't any reordering.

> Do method calls on a volatile variable act as volatile writes?

No.

The calls themselves have no specific synchronizing behaviour, but they are preceded by a volatile read (naturally).

> ... what I actually need is for other threads to see the effects of doA before those of doB.

Then the code must be written so that there is proper synchronization when the state changed by the respective calls is accessed.  Technically, there needs to be proper "happens-before" ordering between the writes on one thread and subsequent reads on other threads ... for all of the state that is affected by the method calls.

No magic.  No short-cuts.  Just properly written synchronization.